# How to call a method until it returns true every x minutes

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, sleep

I have a main thread which will call the below `process` method from a different class..

Now what I am want to do is, if `i=1` then, I will make a call to `checkValue` method and if it returns `false`, then I would like to sleep for two minutes and then again make a call to `checkValue` method, and if it still returns `false`, then again sleep for two minutes, and then again try `checkValue` method but now suppose if it returns `true`, then I would go for `i=2` iteration, otherwise not.

```
public void process(String workflowName) {

    ..// some other code here

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        try {
            .. // some other code here

            if (!checkValue()) {
                Thread.sleep(120000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


private boolean checkValue() throws Exception {
    boolean check_nodes = false;
    return check_nodes;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

I would like to go for `i=2` for loop iteration only when `checkValue` method returns true.. So in short, I need to keep on calling `checkValue` method until it returns true every 2 minutes.

Once it returns true, I won't call `checkValue` method for `i=1`, but for `i=2`, I will do the same thing again.

Comment: if it returns true third time, you want to sleep?

Comment: Thread.sleep(2000); equals sleeping for 2 seconds, 2 minutes would be Thread.sleep(120000);

Comment: @Batty: No I don't want to sleep then, if it returns true third time.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind: That was by mistake.. Silly me..

Comment: use break in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(millis)` suspends the current thread.

So you have to call `Thread.sleep(2 * 60 * 1000)` in the main thread, to sleep for two minutes.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Yup that was by mistake. Copy paste mistake. How about my original question? How do I keep on calling checkValue method every few minutes if returns false.

Comment: In my question, I just don't want to sleep.. I would like to go for `i=2` for loop iteration only when `checkValue` method returns true.. So in short, I need to keep on calling `checkValue` method until it returns true every 2 minutes.

Comment: consider reading the chapter "while loops" in the introduction of the programming lamguage.: while(!isResultReceived && i < 2) { isResultReceived = check(); Thread.sleep(2*60*120); i++}

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 1;
while ( i <=10 ){
    try{
         if(!checkValue()){
             Thread.sleep(120000);
         } else{
                i++;
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: How this will work? In this what is happening, after sleeping for two minutes, it goes back to for loop for `i=2` which is what I don't want.. If it returns true, then only I want to go for `i=2` for loop.

Comment: I would like to go for `i=2` for loop iteration only when `checkValue` method returns true.. So in short, I need to keep on calling `checkValue` method until it returns true every 2 minutes.

Comment: i is still 1. I only increments to two if checkValue is true.

Answer (score 0):

Use **break** if you don't want to continue the loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    try {
        .. // some other code here

        if (!checkValue()) {
            Thread.sleep(2000 * 60);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How this will work? In this what is happening, after sleeping for two minutes, it goes back to for loop for `i=2` which is what I don't want.. If it returns true, then only I want to go for `i=2` for loop.

Comment: I would like to go for `i=2` for loop iteration only when `checkValue` method returns true.. So in short, I need to keep on calling `checkValue` method until it returns true every 2 minutes.